# Error Updating Laravel 5.4 to 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

Method Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump is not callable, can not call post-autoload-dump script

> @php artisan package:discover

There are no commands defined in the "package" namespace.

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Comment: So, what is you question? What did you do to get this error? Please add more context.

Comment: Same thing. Just updated composer.json as in upgrade guide and ran composer update.

Comment: Hm... Of course it's not callable, there's no such method because I've accidently changed 5.4->5.3 instead of 5.4->5.5 in my composer.json.

Answer (score 1):

This would normally happen if the version of laravel in your `composer.json` file is under `5.5`.

You will want to make sure you have:

```
"laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
```

In the require portion of the json. Sometimes, if you update through composer, it will load the package from the cache. You might want to delete your `$PROJECT_DIR/vendor/*` folder and then run:

`composer update --prefer-source`

Notice the output to see that `laravel/framework` is indeed at `5.5.*`.